# OpenTest support for Dojo toolkit

Tags: dojo, opentest

I'm trying to use OpenTest with web applications created with IBM EGL using the Dojo toolkit. The issue with dojo is that it dynamically generates id's every time so they cannot be used as a locator. In addition many elements do not have an xpath so that can't be used either.

It seems like this is a common issue when I search for "dojo" and "selenium" but I haven't found any solutions yet.

Other testing tools have "explicit" support for specific frameworks (e.g. like dojo) so I assume it's technically feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excerpt from a website where this same question was asked and OpenTest supports building out macros that do just what this indvidual was able to do with .NET code. Please reference the blockquote below as well as the [source](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Selenium-Web-Driver-Test-for-Dojo-Dijits-td3995391.html)

> I use Selenium to Test my web application which is built by dojo/dijit
>   and asp.net MVC, so far it works fine.
>
> I've faced the same issues with yours before. My way is "don't think
>   about dojo widgets" when writing steps interacting with them. Treat
>   them as normal complex html elements. You need to browse your dom tree
>   on the client after dojo parse your widgets, locate the real dom
>   element which dijit's value node or interactive part corresponding to
>   and do thing (Click, SendKey or GetId in your case) to it.
>
> It is also good to wrap some common actions to widgets into Helpers
>   which can be reused in your project.
>
> Below is a simple .NET example I use to test whether a button exist in
>   a dGrid, I just use css selector to find the cell, hope it helps:

```
       [Then("I can delete it at row '(.*)'")] 
        public void Then_I_can_delete_it_at_row(int rowIndex) 
        { 
            var nthRow = Browser.FindElementsChecked(By.CssSelector(".dgrid-content .dgrid-row-table")).ElementAt(rowIndex - 1); 
            var deleteBtnsInRow = nthRow.FindElementsChecked(By.XPath(".//span[text() = 'Delete']")); 
            Assert.AreEqual(1, deleteBtnsInRow.Count); 
        }
```